# Angular 4, изменение значений компонента из другого компонента

Tags: маршрутизация, angular4, компоненты, render

Здравствуйте! Есть 4 компонента app, home, page, menu.
App содержит следующий код:

```
<div id="wrapper">

<router-outlet></router-outlet>

<app-menu></app-menu></div>
```

Как видите меню отображается в 2 модулях ( home & page )
Роутинг содержит следующий код:

```
{
    path : '',
    component: HomeComponent
},
{
    path : 'page',
    component: PageComponent
},
{
    path : 'page/:code',
    component: PageComponent
}
```

Если мы на странице компонента home и переходим на страницу page/:code то данные адекватно меняются в шаблоне . Если же мы на странице page/:code и переходим на страницу page/:code то рендеринг шаблона не происходит с новыми данными - остаются старые ( при перезагрузки страницы подтягиваются нужные данные ) . То есть не происходит рендеринг компонента если переход был со страницы page/:code на страницу page/:code.
Если обратно вернутся на страницу home и перейти на страницу page/:code то рендеринг происходит.

Компоненты я не выкладываю так как там просто переопределение переменных которые выводятся в шаблоне.

Answer (score 0):

Если не был изменён компонент, то конструктор и ngOnInit не вызываются повторно.
Что бы достичь желаемого результата, как я понимаю, вам нужно сделать следующее:
1) В конструктор добавить private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute что бы получилось что-то такое:

```
constructor(public meta : Meta, public  title: Title, private http: Http, private router: Router, private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute)
```

Добавив private вы автоматически создаёте поле класса с таким же именем и типом.
2) Советую убрать код из конструктора и поместить его в новую функцию, например loadData(code)
3) Как я уже писал ранее, код в конструкторе и ngOnInit не срабатывает дважды находясь в одном компоненте. Что бы отследить изменение адреса я использую activatedRoute. Для в начале метода ngOnInit:

```html
this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe(variables=> this.loadData(variables.code));
```